# Connecting to users local machine from my WebApp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, saas

I have a Web App that i have developed I am looking to develop a plugin for this app so that i can pull information from the users accounts package such as sage or quickbooks(offline version). Ideally I would like to do this without them having to have a static ip etc.

Unfortunately this is way over my head I currently have no idea on how to do this.

Please can some one guide me in the right direction I will probably use json data between the webapp and the client service that I will make and im fine with that part its just the initial connection that I am confused about.

Any help would be really really appreciated I hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Ash

Comment: What tools are you prepared to use? What kind of software can users install? A Java app embedded in the browser that asks for special permissions might be all you need.

Comment: i would prefer something in .net on the client side as i know both quickbooks and sage support this. maybe some sort of a service that can run in the system tray so the user can switch it on and off easily?

Answer (score 0):

The way the Shopify Quickbooks integration ([Quickify](http://apps.shopify.com/quickify)) works is by setting up a tiny local server that listens on a high port number and is able to play with the local filesystem. The web app part of the solution sends JSON back to it.

Comment: This sounds exactly like what i need to be doing however im still struggling to understand how can get my webapp talking to the client without a static ip? cheers!

Comment: You probably need to expose some kind of API to whatever client application you're using or building.

Comment: i was thinking more along the lines of a socket? I'm not sure if an api will beable to keep connections open and query the connection when the data is needed?